# Subpixel rendering makes text blurry in Blink engine

Tags: css

So I'm pretty sure many of you have noticed that a couple of months ago the folks over at Chromium changed the behaviour of their rendering engine when it comes to non-integer pixel values. Text now seems to be blurry which broke a considerable amount of pages using the popular `transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);` centering. (example: http://eiskis.net)

Nevertheless, I couldn't find any according questions on this platform yet and the solutions for blurry texts are always the same old ones (`-webkit-font-smoothing`, `translateZ(0)` etc.) which actually don't work in this case.

So - besides using flexbox - does anyone know a way around this new blurryness?

Comment: Ehm... can you post screenshots of the differences? Also, what platform?

Comment: Screenshots from example page including DevTools BoxModel from left one: http://i.imgur.com/1Ljvik0.png?1
The problem occurs exactly when transform offsets are not integers.
I run Windows 10 on my PC but I'm also able to reproduce this on OS X (Yosemite and El Capitan).

Comment: Actually, the example works fine on OS X. But the slightest change of the `.centerify`box will make it blurry there as well, just as in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);` use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Avoid using translate3d with Chrome if you can help it for the time being. There are several bugs already known on Chrome (and some bug with CSS itself) with 3d transformation.

Comment: Well that's actually where I came from when I noticed the issue. Respectively what I did was like `transformX(-50%) transformY(-50%)` and that was definitely blurry, too.

Comment: Whatever, that now seems to solve the issue. Maybe there was a fix in the Chrome 47 release or something like that. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out! (Can't give you the bounty before 22 hours, you're going to receive it then.)

Comment: Hey no problem. Are you sure about the fix not working before? Because I'm pretty sure I just helped a friend with the exact same bug several days ago...

Comment: I'm sure that I originally encountered the problem without using `transform3d`. So I guess something in the browser engine was fixed.